# How can I find User's provider Id in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am newbie, and may be the question is stupidly but I am wondering. How can I find User's provider id in Azure Active Directory? I looked up everywhere but I didn't find anything. May I confused jargon for Azure AD? If it is. At least I am going to learn jargon.

Comment: What do you mean by `User's Provider Id`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more on what exactly is implied by "User's provider ID"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by **User's Provider Id** in your context.

Based on my understanding, you are referring to either Azure ***User Object ID*** or Azure ***Tenant ID***

Please check below that may give you some clarity regarding this:

##### User Object ID:

Object ID is a property having unique value that is used to identify the user in Azure AD.

In order to find the **`Object ID`** of Azure AD User,

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Users -> All Users -> Select specific User -> Profile***

[image]

##### Azure Tenant ID:

Tenant ID is a globally unique identifier (GUID) of the Azure Active Directory instance.

In order to find the value of **`Tenant ID`** ,

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Overview***

[image]